# JSON encoding NDB entities with keys

Tags: python, json, serialization, encoding, app-engine-ndb

I'm trying to create a CRUD application with Google Cloud ndb and REST architecture.

Therefore I have different API calls for creating and retrieving.

Now to update the entities I need to display them in the front end but also give an identifier, so ndb knows which entity to update later.

I try to get the entities with `model.query` and then encode them to JSON with an extended encoder to serialize `datetime` and `ndb.Key`:

```
# JSONEncoder extension to handle datetime & ndb.Key
class CustomJsonEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, datetime):
            return obj.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')
        if isinstance(obj, ndb.Key):
            return obj.urlsafe()
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

# Get JSON data from ndb
query = Card.query(Card.category==category, ancestor=ancestor_key()).fetch()
cards = json.dumps([c.to_dict() for c in query], cls=CustomJsonEncoder)
                self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
                self.response.out.write(cards)
```

My problem now is that the entity key just disappears and isn't shown in the `json.dump` anymore. I don't get any errors, it's just not encoded and passed along.

The `datetime` object is shown correctly when printed. Any ideas on how I can send the URL safe ndb key along with the `json.dump`?

Answer (score 0):

You're dumping `Card` entity objects, which do **not** include the respective object keys. To confirm this just temporarily add a logging statement like this to your `CustomJsonEncoder`:

```
if isinstance(obj, ndb.Key):
    logging.error('key found: %s' % obj.urlsafe())
    return obj.urlsafe()
```

You need to explicitly add the entity keys to the data to be json-encoded if you want them.

Or you could use a `ComputedProperty` in that entity's model (but then you'd be wasting some storage):

```
key_str = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: self.key.urlsafe())
```